# Are all vertical asymptotes the points where the denominator is zero?

Tags: calculus

Question 1: Are all vertical asymptotes the points where the denominator is zero?

Question 2: For all rational functions ( fractions of polynomials), are all vertical asympototes the points where the denominator is zero?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Not necessarily, there are also "removable singularities", for example $\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x.-1}$ at $x_0=1$ which has no vertical asymptote.

Comment: Perhaps one example to think about is $f(x) = \tan x$ ...

Comment: Well $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, and since $\sin x, \cos x$ are continuous everywhere, the only vertical asymptotes are when $\cos x = 0$. A better example is $g(x) = \ln x$ as James A has mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1: No. In general, vertical asymptotes do not need to be zeroes of the donimanator. Consider the function $f(x)=\ln(x)$. It has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$, but it does not even have a denominator.

For question 2: Yes. For all rational functions (fractions of polynomials), vertical asymptotes are always at the zeroes of the denominator. The only values for which a rational function will be undefined is at the zeroes of its denominator, because polynomials are continuous everywhere. So necessarily, all vertical asymptotes must be at the zeroes of the denominator, as these are the only places the function is undefined.